# Kafka consumer offset commit failed: NotCoordinatorForGroupException

Tags: apache-kafka, failover

Kafka broker version is kafka_2.11-0.10.2.1
My clients are using kafka-clients(0.10.2.0) package from org.apache.kafka

"auto commit" is enabled. Around the time the group co-ordinator broker was restarted, my consumers throw this error and I could see the processing is duplicated for these messages.

```
    Offset commit with offsets {topic1-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=9, metadata=''}, topic2-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=9, metadata=''}, topic3-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=11, metadata=''}} failed for group myGroupId: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RetriableCommitFailedException: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing offsets.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotCoordinatorForGroupException: This is not the correct coordinator for this group.
```

My questions:

1. To which node does Kafka consumers commit offset? To the partition leader or to the group coordinator?
2. During co-ordinator failover, does consumers reattempt offset commit to the new Group co-ordinator?

Comment: The offsets are committed to the `__consumer_offsets` topic. So my guess is, it shall behave like any common producer producing msg to an arbitrary topic (i.e. partition leader)

Comment: I understand the offsets are stored in __consumer_offsets. But how do the consumers commit offset to Kafka? Do they send it to the partition leader or to the group coordinator? Do they retry?